# Combine multiple rows with different column values into a single one

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to create a single row starting from multiple ones and combining them based on different column values; here is the result i reached based on the following query:

```
select distinct ID, case info when 'name' then value end as 'NAME', case info when 'id' then value end as 'serial'
FROM TABLENAME t 
WHERE info = 'name' or info = 'id'
```

[image]

Howerver the expected result should be something along the lines of

[image]

I tried with `group by` clauses but that doesn't seem to work.
The RDBMS is Microsoft SQL Server.
Thanks

Comment: do a max(col) group by id. it will give you values without NULLs.

Comment: This is a `PIVOT`: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT Id AS x, Info, Value FROM Data) t PIVOT (MAX(Value) FOR Info IN ([name], [id])) p` (I assume, that your table has these columns - `Id`, `Info`, `Value`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT X.ID,MAX(X.NAME)NAME,MAX(X.SERIAL)AS SERIAL   FROM
(
  SELECT 100 AS ID, NULL AS NAME, '24B6-97F3'AS SERIAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 100,'A',NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 200,NULL,'8113-B600'UNION ALL
  SELECT 200,'B',NULL
)X
GROUP BY X.ID
```

For me GROUP BY works

Comment: the provided solution leads to the expected result. i tried with something similar but didn't use the `MAX` function and that's why the `GROUP BY` didn't work for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A simple `PIVOT` operator can achieve this for dynamic results:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT id AS id_column, info, value
  FROM tablename 
) src
PIVOT
(
  MAX(value) FOR info IN ([name], [id])
) piv
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

**Result:**

```
| id_column | name | id         |
|-----------|------|------------|
| 100       | a    | 24b6-97f3  |
| 200       | b    | 8113-b600  |
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/lvh8zdeh).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of a self join for things like this

```
SELECT tName.ID, tName.Value AS Name, tSerial.Value AS Serial
FROM TableName AS tName
INNER JOIN TableName AS tSerial ON tSerial.ID = tName.ID AND tSerial.Info = 'Serial'
WHERE tName.Info = 'Name'
```

This initially selects only the Name rows, then self joins on the same IDs and now filter to the Serial rows. You may want to change the INNER JOIN to a LEFT JOIN if not everything has a Name and Serial and you want to know which Names don't have a Serial